# how to finish my recyclerView OnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implement a RecyclerView OnClickListener to open different new activity when we click on different item of the recycler View. I have doing all but it get one error in my Fragement :

```
        verticalRecyclerView.adapter = MuscleAdapter(context, muscleList, OnGroupClickListener)
        verticalRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(MuscleItemDecoration())

        return view
```

In my code to find my recycler View, I get an error at the  `MuscleAdapter(context, muscleList, OnGroupClickListener)`, and it says : *Classifier 'OnGroupClickListener' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here*
My Adapter looks that (it isn't finished but it contains no error message):

```
        val context: MainActivity,
        private val muscleList: ArrayList<MuscleModel>,
        private val onGroupClickListener: OnGroupClickListener)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<MuscleAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    //box to stock components
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val muscleImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image)
        val muscleName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name_item)
        val muscleDescription: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.description_item)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_muscular_group, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)     {
        // stocks values of "muscle group"
        val currentItem = muscleList[position]

        //update values of the Muscle Group
        holder.muscleName.text = currentItem.name
        holder.muscleDescription.text = currentItem.description
        holder.muscleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.drawable)

        //window open when click ?

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            onGroupClickListener.onGroupItemClicked(position)
            if (position == 0) {
                CommentairePopup(this).show()
            } else if (position == 1) {
            } else if (position == 2) {
            } else if (position == 3) {
            } else if (position == 4) {
            } else if (position == 5) {
            } else if (position == 6) {
            }
        }
    }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = muscleList.size
}
```

EDIT :
that is my OnGroupClickListener sorry, and it is an interface :

```
    fun onGroupItemClicked(position : Int)
}
```

How can I suppress the error message from my Fragment ?
Thanks very much for any help !

Comment: What is `OnGroupClickListener`? If it is an interface then you need to have a concrete implementation of it, otherwise what do you think it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is incorrect because you're not specifying an instance of an object that implements the `OnGroupClickListener` interface, but rather, just the interface's name itself.

Here's a potential fix:

```
    verticalRecyclerView.adapter = MuscleAdapter(context, muscleList, object : OnGroupClickListener {
        override fun onGroupClick(parent: ExpandableListView!, v: View!, groupPosition: Int, id: Long) {
           //Your implementation here...
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, when you write that i can do my implementation you mean that I can choose which page match with which item ? And it mean that I remove that from my Adapteur ?

Comment: See this for details:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener#summary

Comment: I am sorry for taking your time but I am a rookie and I don't find what should I implement in the onGroupClick. Thank you